# how to set custom revision number in SVN repository from 10000

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server, visualsvn

I have lost my svn server and now want to setup new svnserver with more revision number than of my working copy i. e. if  my working copy have last revision is 950  then i want to setup new repository start from 1000. I am using visualSVN server for new svn setup and nothing i left on
old server except my working copy.

Comment: Just import the data from your working copy into a new clean repository. The snapshot of your project will be commmitted into the repository as revision 1. Normally there should be no reasons to start a new repository with any revision except 1.

Comment: @bahrep Unfortunately, this leaves me with failed commits because the working copy and the new repo are out of sync with regards to their revision numbers.

Comment: @Reahreic you cannot use your existing working copy with the re-created repository. But you can import data from it and checkout a new working copy. Instead. I did not say that you can continue using a working copy checked out from a different repository.